# Conditional expected value of a product of two independent normal variables

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, products, expectation

I'm trying to work out the following conditional expectation:

$E[\epsilon_t z_t|\epsilon_t + z_t = k, \epsilon_{t-1}, z_{t-1}, \epsilon_{t-2}, z_{t-2},...]$

where $k$ is known and $\epsilon_{t}$ and $z_t$ are independent and normal distributed random variables with zero means and variances equal to $\sigma^2$ and $\tau^2$ respectively.

Any hints?

Regards,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume without loss of generality that the random variables $x$ and $y$ are independent and centered normal with variances $\sigma^2$ and $\tau^2$ respectively, and that one looks for $$
E[xy\mid x+y].
$$
Let $z=x+y$, then $t=\tau^2x-\sigma^2y$ is independent of $z$ since $(z,t)$ is centered normal and $E[zt]=0$, and 
$$
(\sigma^2+\tau^2)\cdot(x,y)=(\sigma^2z+t,\tau^2z-t),
$$
hence 
$$
(\sigma^2+\tau^2)^2xy=\sigma^2\tau^2z^2+(\tau^2-\sigma^2)zt-t^2.
$$
Note that $E[z^2\mid z]=z^2$, $E[t^2\mid z]=E[t^2]=\tau^2\sigma^2(\sigma^2+\tau^2)$, $E[zt\mid z]=zE[t\mid z]$ and $E[t\mid z]=E[t]=0$. Hence,
$$
(\sigma^2+\tau^2)^2E[xy\mid z]=\sigma^2\tau^2z^2-\tau^2\sigma^2(\sigma^2+\tau^2),
$$
that is,
$$
E[xy\mid x+y]=\frac{\sigma^2\tau^2}{(\sigma^2+\tau^2)^2}\left((x+y)^2-(\sigma^2+\tau^2)\right).
$$

Comment: This assumes that in the question $(\epsilon_t,z_t)$ is independent of $(\epsilon_s,z_s)_{s\leqslant t-1}$.

Comment: Could you explain why $E[t^2∣z]=E[t^2]$?

Comment: What is E[u|v] when $(u,v) is independent?

Comment: It's clearly equal to $E[u]$. But in the previous problem we have that $t$ and $z$ are independent not $t^2$ and $z$.

Comment: "Two random variables $X$ and $Z$ are independent" translates into "all functions $g(X)$ are independent of all functions $h(Z)$".

Comment: @Did Is it a common proof in mathematics? Or did you come up with it by yourself?

Comment: Trying to find $t$ such that $(z,t)$ is independent gaussian is natural. The rest follows.